# Is it possible to use ADODB::_RecordsetPtr object as member data?

Tags: c++, memory, ado

I am wrting a class in C++. Here is my code:

```
class MyClass
{
 private:
    ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pConn;
 public:
    MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    pConn = ADODB::_ConnectionPtr("ADODB.Connection");
    // ......
}
```

The problem is, when I try to assign a temporary `ADODB::_ConnectionPtr` object to `pConn`, the compiler throws an exception :`Unhandled exception at at 0x75C9C41F in AccessReader.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x003AF808.`

Is this because `ADODB::_ConnectionPtr` object is not copyable?

How can I fix this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: When you use the smart pointer wrapper types then you *must* handle the _com_error exceptions that it produces when the underlying COM method fails.  Not doing so just produces mystifying unhandled C++ exceptions that don't tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you're setting a `_RecordsetPtr` to a `_ConnectionPtr`.

Here are other things to check:

Have you called [CoInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CoInitializeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Try to catch the exception and see what it's complaining about:

```
catch (_com_error &e) {
    std::cerr << e.Description () << std::endl
}
```